# How to create and format an image dataset from scratch for machine learning?

Tags: image, machine-learning, deep-learning

I've only worked with ML with .csv formats. I've worked with image formats too but only premade imagesets (MNIST,etc). If I were to create an imageset from scratch, how are the class labels typically formated? Would I have to manually title the image of a jpeg?

Best, Jeremy

Comment: also, jpeg images cannot have the same title, so wouldn't the ML program recognize every image as its own class if all titles different?

Comment: Perhaps the question should be migrated to *crossvalidate.SE*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've worked with image datasets formatted as:

1. Class Names as Folders : As the name suggests, images belonging to a specific class are filled into the specific folder with the folder name representing the class.

For example for a dataset to classify Cats vs. Dogs

```
-Dataset/
--Cats/
---all cat images here
--Dogs/
---all dogs images here
```

2. Single Folder + Text File : All images are dumped into a single folder - obviously every image file will have a unique name. The key-value pairs of `image_name : class` can be stored as rows in a csv file.

For example

```
-Dataset/
--all images heree
--imagename_class.csv
```

3. Single Folder with Class in filename : All images can be placed in a single folder with the name of the image having the class label with some changing index value.

For example

```
-Dataset/
--cat_1.jpg
--cat_2.jpg
--dog_1.jpg
--cat_3.jpg
--...
```

Hope this helps!